# PHP PEAR Mail '='

Tags: php, email, pear, mime, quoted-printable

When sending out HTML emails via PEAR, although it renders correctly on email clients, when looking at the message source the text has lots of `=` signs.

**Example**

> blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>   blah=blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>   blah blah blah blah=blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>   blah blah blah blah blah blah= blah blah blah blah blah blah

Any ideas why and how they can be removed?  Do they cause any issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part of the (oldschool but still used!) quoted-printable encoding that represents a 8-bit ASCII string in 7-bit ASC codeset. All characters that are >127 are encoded in the form `=F3`, which is a hexadecimal representation of the character. Read more at [Wikipedia on quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

To read the message, you must apply [`quoted_printable_decode()`](http://en.php.net/manual/de/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) to the string. or use a proper MIME Mail decoder that will resolve other issue's that you will encounter when trying to parse mails, too.

It does not cause issues - it solves them.

Answer (score 1):

They are part of the quoted-printable encoding and must be present in order to read the message properly.